# linking the color resource file

Tags: android, android-layout

I come through his error:
Couldn't resolve resource @color/teal_200
i modify the color resource file

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#ffe400</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffa600</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#272727</color>
    <color name="lightWhite">#f5f5f5</color>
    <color name="white">#fff</color>
    <color name="black">#000</color>
```

how I fix this error?

Comment: I dont see a color named teal_200.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a color named "teal_200" yet. You need to define one; you can add this to `color.xml`:

```
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
```